# Logging JWT Bearer authentication and validation in OWIN

Tags: c#, jwt, owin

I am using JWT Token validation in my project and things are working fine. Below is the sample I am using.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
         AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
         TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
             {
                  ValidAudience = OpenIDConfiguration.ClientId,
                  ValidIssuer = authority,
                  IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                  {
                       var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                       return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
                  }
             }
    });
```

This piece seems to work fine, if the token validation fails I get error as forbidden in API response and if its successful, I get the valid response.
In either cases it returns the signingkeys which is being validated by OWIN pipeline I believe. I want to log error or exception if the signingkeys validation fails. How do I understand if the validation failed or passed.
Want to understand where that magic happens.

Comment: You can configure OWIN logger or redirect its logs to the logger you already use. Or simply extend `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` in the `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` and log the reason. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578498/how-to-log-authentication-failure-reasons-when-using-owin-and-jwt

Comment: Thanks for the post. This was a savior.  Was able to find my error and log it.